# What is the purpose of the "where" builtin in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I found it impossible to google this, and couldn't find info in the man pages.

Comment: My bash don't have a `where` keyword. And I never heard that. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you run `command -v where`?

Comment: has something made an alias or bash function for you?  type 'set | less' and look at the result...

Comment: My bad. It's specific to zsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html:

> where [ -wpms ] name ...
>   Equivalent to whence -ca.

and:

> whence [ -vcwfpams ] name ... For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a command name.
>
> -v Produce a more verbose report.
>
> -c Print the results in a csh-like format. This takes precedence over -v.
>
> -w For each name, print ‘name: word’ where word is one of alias, builtin, command, function, hashed, reserved or none, according as
>   name corresponds to an alias, a built-in command, an external command,
>   a shell function, a command defined with the hash builtin, a reserved
>   word, or is not recognised. This takes precedence over -v and -c.
>
> -f Causes the contents of a shell function to be displayed, which would otherwise not happen unless the -c flag were used.
>
> -p Do a path search for name even if it is an alias, reserved word, shell function or builtin.
>
> -a Do a search for all occurrences of name throughout the command path. Normally only the first occurrence is printed.
>
> -m The arguments are taken as patterns (should be quoted), and the information is displayed for each command matching one of these
>   patterns.
>
> -s If a pathname contains symlinks, print the symlink-free pathname as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [`zsh` builtins manual](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshbuiltins) describes it:

> where [ -wpms ] name ...
>       Equivalent to whence -ca.

--

> whence [ -vcwfpams ] name ...
>       For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a command name.
>
> -c     Print the results in a csh-like format. This takes precedence over
>
> -a     Do a search for all occurrences of name throughout the command path. Normally only the first occurrence is printed. -v.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documented list of reserved words, `where` is not a keyword in bash.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html